# HTML background stopped working in GMail emails

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, html-table

I have been opening the locally hosted email in chrome, selecting all, copying, and pasting into GMail for many years now. 2-3 days ago it started posting the bgcolor instead of the image even though no code or process was changed. Is there an updated way to do this now?

Here is the doc: http://www.homesnappers.com/email2.html

Here is a snippet of the code:

```html
<table data-module="Layou-1" data-bgcolor="Background Color" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#494c50" class="currentTable">
    <tr>
  
  <td data-bg="Main BG" align="center" background="http://www.homesnappers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/bg-2.jpg" style="background-size:cover; background-position:top;"><table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried more css way like so? `background:url(yourimage.jpg) / cover` I would try it without the css3 styling cause i believe `background-size:cover; ` does not work on gmail and could be brekaing it

Comment: Where would I put that? I apologize, I am quite a novice.

www.homesnappers.com/email2.html